# Linking Button Onclick With Select Menu Onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a select menu that has an onchange function that will print an HTML message when a new option is selected. I also have a button that has an onclick function that will change the current celected option in the select menu, however, when the button is clicked and the select menu is changed, the onchange function does not initiate. How can I get the onchange function to work when I click the button? I do not want to merely initiate the onchange function as an onclick option in the button because I want to change the select menu as well.

```
<html>
    <select id="sel" onchange='myFunction()'>
        <option value="car">1</option>
        <option value="bike">2</option>
        <option value="cycle">3</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick='selectChange()'>Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }

    function selectChange(){
        document.getElementById('sel').value = "bike";
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `myFunction()` from *within* `selectChange()`:

```html
<html>
<select id="sel" onchange='myFunction()'>
  <option value="car">1</option>
  <option value="bike">2</option>
  <option value="cycle">3</option>
</select>

<button onclick='selectChange()'>Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
  }

  function selectChange() {
    document.getElementById('sel').value = "bike";
     myFunction();
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Note, however, that you should also make use of *[Unobstructive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)*, and use *[event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)* rather than `onchange` and `onclick`:

```js
document.getElementById('sel').addEventListener('change', myFunction);
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', selectChange);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}

function selectChange() {
  document.getElementById('sel').value = "bike";
  myFunction();
}
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option value="car">1</option>
  <option value="bike">2</option>
  <option value="cycle">3</option>
</select>

<button>Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! The recommendation to use unobtrusive javascript is exactly what I needed / should be doing.